# problem in return function , why function is return undefined

Tags: javascript, function, return

This function most return true or false but its return undefined...

```
class Admin() {
  //function check if the username alredy used ,, error in return of function
  checkUserNameIsUsed(userName, tableName, proprtieName) {
    try {
      let sqlQuery = `select * from ${tableName} where ${proprtieName} = '${userName}'`;
      connectToMysql();
      connection.connect((err) => {
        if (!err) {
          connection.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => {
            if (!err) {
              if (result.length > 0) {
                console.log("this user name is used :", userName);
                return false;
              } else {
                return true;
              }
            }
            connection.end();
          })
        } else {
          console.log(err);
          connection.end();
          return false;
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

above in this code I 'am try to check is the DB is already have username or not , if function found the user name it most return false and if not found it's return true.

and in this code I check if the function return false or true but its return undefined

```
//check if user name is used
if (admin.checkUserNameIsUsed(adminUserName,adminTable,adminUserNameInDB)===false){
  res.status(400).send("thie user name is used please choose another username");
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkUserNameIsUsed function is making a database query, which is an asynchronous operation.When you try to return true or false inside the callback functions, you're actually returning from those inner functions, not from the checkUserNameIsUsed function itself.

To solve this here you can use callbacks or promises.

```
class Admin {
  //function check if the username already used ,, error in return of function
  async checkUserNameIsUsed(userName, tableName, propertyName) {
    try {
      let sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM ${tableName} WHERE ${propertyName} = '${userName}'`;
      await connectToMysql();
      
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            connection.end();
            reject(err);
          } else {
            if (result.length > 0) {
              console.log("This username is already used:", userName);
              connection.end();
              resolve(false);
            } else {
              connection.end();
              resolve(true);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use function like this

```
async function someFunction() {
  const admin = new Admin();
  try {
    const isUserNameUsed = await admin.checkUserNameIsUsed('someUserName', 'tableName', 'propertyName');
    console.log(isUserNameUsed); // It will log either true or false
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error);
  }
}

someFunction();
```